# Control submenus width in css dropdown menu

Tags: css, html, menu

I'm posting here to get some help.

I'm trying to make a simple dropdown menu and I'm stacked with the submenus (limpieza and balance).

What i'm trying to achieve here is to make the limpieza and balance buttons have the same width and text align as the rest of the buttons. I just dont know how. It looks like once the relative attribute is added to the container and the absolute attribute is added to limpieza and balance, I can't control their width or text align anymore. I guess is bc they are out of its cointainer. I'm really confused here since this is the first time I try css.

I would appreciate if some1 could provide some help.

Here is the code.

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

body {
 font-family: Cambria, "Hoefler Text", "Liberation Serif", Times, "Times New Roman", serif; 
 }

/*ESTILOS GENERALES*/

.header {
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background:white;
    }

.barrasup {
 background:#203c6e;
 padding-top: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 min-height: 29px;
    z-index: 2;
}

.contenedor {
 margin: 0 auto;
 max-width: 1200px;
  }

.social {
 background: #203c6e;
 display: block;
 float: none;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 width: 75px;
}

.instasocsup {
 margin-right: 10px
}

/*MENU*/

.barrainf {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.menu {
    width: 1180px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.menu ul {
 list-style:none;
 padding: 0;
}

.menu li {
    line-height: 2.5rem;
    position: relative;

 }
 
.menu li .item2 ul {
     position: absolute;
 }

.menu > ul > li > div > a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color: black;
    display: block;
}

.menu > ul > li > div > a:hover {
    color: white;
    background: #203c6e;   
}

.menu > ul > li > div > a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color: black;
    display: block;
}

.menu > ul > li > div > a:hover {
    color: white;
    background: #203c6e;   
}

.menu > ul > li > div > ul > li >div > a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color: white;
    display: block;
}

.menu li ul {
    display: none;
}


.menu li:hover ul {
    display:block;
}

.item1 {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background: white;
} 

.item2, .item3, .item4, .item5  {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background:white;
}

.subitem1, .subitem2 {
    margin-left: 0px;
    background: #203C6E;
    color: white;
}

/*1ER NIVEL*/


.menu > ul{
    background: #DF2529;
    display: table;
    width:100%;
    }

.menu > ul > li {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento sin título</title>
<link href="css/styleIndigo.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="header">
  <div class="barrasup">
   <div class="contenedor">
    <div class="social">
    <a href="#" class="instasocsup"><img src="Instagram_logo.png"></img></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="twitter_logo.png"></img></a>
                </div>
             </div>
          </div>
          
        <div class="barrainf">
            <div class="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><div class="item1"><a href="#">Inicio</a></div></li>
                <li><div class="item2"><a href="#">Comprar</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li id="listamenu"><div class="subitem1"><a href="#">Balance</a></div></li>
                        <li id="listamenu"><div class="subitem2"><a href="#">Limpieza</a></div></li>
                    </ul>
                </div></li>
                <li><div class="item3"><a href="#">Blog</a></div></li>
                <li><div class="item4"><a href="#">Quienes somos</a></div></li>
                <li><div class="item5"><a href="#">Contacto</a></div></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
  </div> 
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use calculate css for width that works with inherited table display properties. View it here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/reMpRj

```
.menu > ul > li > div > ul {
  width: calc(100% - 10px);
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you. That's exactly what I was looking for. I appreciate it!